# Handling more than 1000 user pools in AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am developing an app with cognito for authentication and user management in a multi tenant application.

And the app provide a different app per client. Meaning one client will have its own cognito user pool and they get their own domain to login.

So the problem i anticipate in the future is we could reach more than a 1000 clients and the AWS cognitio limit of 1000 will be reached.

In this case the only way i can think of handling this is to create a new AWS account and getting more user pools from that account.

But i dont want to have to manage multiple AWS accounts in the future. I dont think we should use the same user pool for maintaining multiple clients because since each client gets their own app.

Not sure what is the best way to handle this.

Comment: This architecture doesn't seem to be scalable. If you can share the specific requirement which forced you to create a different Cognito user pool for each user, we can try solving this issue with a better solution

Comment: @RobinVarghese The though process is that each organization needs to login into their own app so having a seperate cognito pool will help us better manage authentication.

Comment: Also lets say a user in orgA can also be a part of orgB. If i had used a shared cognito pool, i could only create a single user for both the orgs because they are using the same pool. And the same users authorization may be different in the two organizations

Comment: And its differnet cognito pool for each organization not each user.

Comment: Another fear i had for using shared pool is for users in the shared pools being able to login into other organizations application.

Comment: Raise one AWS support ticket to check whether 1000 is a soft limit and what is the hard limit for this count

Comment: looks like 1000 is not a hard limit but i may end up neeeding more than 10k user pools. Not sure i can do that by asking aws do increase the limit. Most probably we need to use multiple aws accountts for that

Comment: You can have 1000 app clients per pool, and 1000 pool per account, so that's 1,000,000 clients per account. Granted, without knowing your use case, if I were you, I would start with this setup: create user pools on the go once you reach 1000 app clients. Afterwards, if/when you approach a million, then think about multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do it would be to use a shared user pool among organizations.

And for each organization i need to create a different `app client` in cognito and make it work in that way.

And for the problem of users in one organization being able login in into other organization's app, due to the shared pool. I will have to create a validation layer before login in the application to to make sure that the username/email has the access to that organization or not.

Comment: I answered a question kind of related to this the other day, it might be worth you giving it a look, specifically the MFA and advanced security costs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143647/multi-tenancy-with-cognito-one-big-user-pool-or-one-pool-per-tenant/66182245#66182245